# MYSQL select query returning undesired results

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have this table in MySQL;
[image]

I am trying to get cc_rowid 10 and cc_type In on row 10 by this query;

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT MAX(cc_rowid),MAX(cc_type)
    FROM clock_clockings
    WHERE cc_eeno =(SELECT cc_eeno FROM clock_clockings WHERE cc_rowid=?)");
```

It is giving me cc_rowid =10 and cc_type=Out.

I am not understanding how to improve this to get desired results. I would appreciate any help on this. thanks

Comment: What do you get when you do max of a string?

Comment: @Minh I **think** it's the largest byte size of the string, but it could just be the longest character length. I also realise this may be a rhetorical question :-p

Comment: `MAX(cc_type)` here is the mistake, we can only use MAX() aggregate function in case of numbers. `Out` has more characters than `In`. So it was displaying cc_type=Out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the cc_type of the max cc_rowid you will need something like:

```
SELECT cc_rowid, cc_type 
FROM clock_clockings 
WHERE cc_rowid = (SELECT max(cc_rowid) FROM clock_clockings);
```

You could do the same with an inner join and the same subquery. Six of one, half a dozen of the other. You could put further WHERE logic in the subquery to filter out anything else you don't want in the `max` aggregation

Comment: This worked great, I then thought i could have used this rather;                                             $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT cc_rowid , cc_type FROM clock_clockings
WHERE cc_out IS NULL AND cc_eeno = (SELECT cu_eeno FROM clock_users WHERE cu_id = ?)");  this will fetch cu_id and will ook for null value in cc_out column @Martin thanks a lot for getting time and answering super fast..obliged

Answer (score 0):

JNevill's answer serves you well. However I want to add how you're current issue is caused:

```
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT MAX(cc_rowid),MAX(cc_type)
    FROM clock_clockings
    WHERE cc_eeno =(SELECT cc_eeno FROM clock_clockings WHERE cc_rowid=?)");
```

You are currently trying to grab the MAX value for `cc_rowid` and for `cc_type`, as the cc_type data is a string it is getting the one wwith the largest content - the longest - that is why the "Out" is being presented.

You do not need the MAX on this selection, so try:

```
   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT MAX(cc_rowid), cc_type
        FROM clock_clockings
        WHERE cc_eeno =(SELECT cc_eeno FROM clock_clockings WHERE cc_rowid=?)");
```

Comment: this solution will not give the cc_type of the max cc_rowid, it also missed a group by cc_type but again it will not give the cc_type of the max cc_rowid, it gives the max of cc_rowid per each cc_type